# Rails: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'paperclip'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm creating a webapp through a tutorial and facing to this problem.

```
in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'paperclip'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/MyName/Desktop/AppName/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mime-types-data-3.2016.0521/data/mime.content_type.column
```

I searched about this topic and tried installing nodejs and added `gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby` but none of them worked for me. 
I cannot use a command `rails s` nor `rake db:migrate` right now, and it happened suddenly so no idea the cause of it.

If anybody has an idea or knows a solution, I would appreciate if you answer me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you `bundle install` after adding the gem

Comment: it missing gem 'paperclip', maybe add it to your Gemfile (if any?) or typing 'gem install paperclip' in terminal

Comment: I read the error on terminal carefully and I realized that some files are missing (probably because I accidentally deleted while sorting out my storage). I cloned a file from github and made it recover. Thank you for your reply and help. It is always good to go back to the last commit, that's the lesson I learned!